# Why does my PowerShell script not name the match groups?

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-group

I have a small PowerShell script which parses log files to pull out certain lines and bring them into an ArrayList.

```
[regex]$regex = "(?'datetime'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{1,3}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}).*" #shortened for ease of understanding
$results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Get-ChildItem 'C:\debug-*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_ | Where-Object {$_ -match $regex} | ForEach-Object {
        $match = $regex.Match($_)
        $obj = New-Object psobject
        foreach ($group in $match.Groups) {
            if ($group.Name -ne "0") {
                $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $group.Name -NotePropertyValue $group.Value
            }
        }
        $results.Add($obj)
    }
}
```

On my development PC it works, on one Windows 2012 server it works but on another I get an error because `$group.Name` is null. On that machine there's never a `Name` property in a `Match`'s groups.

It appears this was added in .NET 1.1 but the server is Windows 2012 which comes with PowerShell 3.0 and .NET 4 installed.

Comment: @Olaf I tried that, no difference.

Comment: Do you have a sample line from the log file that you expect the pattern to match?

Comment: I suggest using `foreach ($group in $match.Groups | Select -Skip 1 )` instead of checking the group names. You can then omit `if ($group.Name -ne "0") {}` condition.

Comment: Ah, I see that you access `$group.Name` in the if block. So, there is only one explanation: there is no match. You should provide the whole regex, not a simplified one, but you need also to check if the file is the same on all servers. Users often get different regex results because they test against different strings/files.

Comment: on my win7ps5.1 setup, this >>> `(?'datetime'\d{4}` <<< errors out. the single quotes are not correct for making a named capture group. i need to use `<>` instead of `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to structure the loop in a different way and use the `$Matches` hashtable rather than `Group` objects.

```
$tmp = $_ -match $regex
foreach ($match in $matches) {
    if ($match -ne "0") {
        $obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $match -NotePropertyValue $matches[$match]
    }
}
```

I'm not clear where `$matches` comes from, but it works.